# Find all possible values of $\frac{1}{{x^2 - x - 1}}$

Tags: functions, inequality, rational-functions

> Question: Find all possible values of $$\frac{1}{{x^2 - x - 1}}$$

My solution-> $\frac{1}{{x^2 - x - 1}}=\frac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{5}{4}}}$
=$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$
=$(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4} \geq -\frac{5}{4}$
=$- \frac{5}{4} \leq (x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4} < \infty$
=$- \frac{5}{4} \geq \frac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4}}} > 0$
=$[-\frac{5}{4}, 0)
$

book showing the answer to be $$\frac{1}{{\left(x-\frac{1}{2} \right)^2 -\frac{5}{4}}} \in \left(-\infty, -\frac{4}{5} \right] \cup (0, +\infty)$$
Please provide the whole process.

Comment: Please do not delete and re-create [a post for which you already recieved comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698813). Instead, edit it.

Comment: Especially since Gerry's comment to your original post hinted to a more rapid solution than the answers below: the range of $x^2-x-1=(x-1/2)^2-5/4$ is $[-5/4,+\infty)$ hence the range of the reciprocal is the set of their reciprocals, i.e. $(-\infty,-4/5]\cup(0,+\infty).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> =$- \frac{5}{4} \leq (x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4} < \infty$
> =$- \frac{5}{4} \geq \frac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4}}} > 0$

$\dfrac{1}{\infty} = 0$, but $\dfrac{1}{-\dfrac{5}{4}} = -\dfrac{5}{4}?$

Also, reconsider the statement $- \dfrac{5}{4} \geq \dfrac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4}}} > 0$. What happens when $(x-\dfrac{1}{2})^2 - \dfrac{5}{4} =0?$

When dealing with the range of complicated functions, always switch to an easier perspective of domain. Ie.

$$\text{Let } y =\dfrac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4}}}, \text{ then the inverse is } \\
x = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{5}{4}} + \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Now, asking to

> find all possible values of $\dfrac{1}{{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2 - \frac{5}{4}}}$

is the same as asking

> what is the domain of the function $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{5}{4}} + \dfrac{1}{2}$, or simply, at what values of $y$ does $x$ exist.

Now, start off seeing the restrictions to the domain. Ie. $\dfrac{1}{y} + \dfrac{5}{4} \geq 0$.

Comment: I think it shoud be `1/y + 5/4 >= 0`

Comment: Indeed. Edited!

Comment: Also, some etiquette advice on this site: 

Its not a crime to delete and repost the same question, but it is honestly a huge waste of effort and time. While, your question will not be closed as a duplicate, consider the time and resources spent by users commenting/answering your old question,... and only to be wasted(deleted) because of some inconsistency to post it all over again, newly, instead of editing it. You will only aim to seek downvotes this way.

Favourable for you, I was unaware of a deleted duplicate at first; only upon seeing @Anne Bauval 's comment...

Comment: ...While I am going delete my efforts now, you will not receive answers in the future for duplicate posting. Here are [some links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to help you out with posting good future questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. first-time user, so you know! The previous question was a mess and had taken too much time to edit in LaTeX, so I preferred to delete it. won't happen again.

Comment: Apologies to clarify my previous comment, I meant to state I will not delete this answer. Typo there :)!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$y = \frac{1}{x^2 - x - 1}$$
Then
\begin{align*}
yx^2 - yx - y & = 1\\
yx^2 - yx - y - 1 & = 0
\end{align*}
which is a quadratic equation in $x$ unless $y = 0$.

If $y = 0$, then
$$\frac{1}{x^2 - x - 1} = 0$$
Multiplying both sides of the equation by $x^2 - x - 1$ yields $1 = 0$, which is a contradiction.  Thus, $0$ is not in the range.

Hence, a real number $y \neq 0$ is in the range of the function if and only if there exists a real number $x$ in the domain of the function that satisfies the quadratic equation $yx^2 - yx - y - 1 = 0$.  A quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ with real coefficients $a, b, c$, where $a \neq 0$, has real roots if and only if its discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$.

\begin{align*}
\Delta & \geq 0\\
(-y)^2 - 4y(-y - 1) & \geq 0\\
y^2 + 4y(y + 1) & \geq 0\\
y^2 + 4y^2 + 4y & \geq 0\\
5y^2 + 4y & \geq 0\\
y(5y + 4) & \geq 0
\end{align*}
Equality holds if
\begin{align*}
y & = 0 & \text{or} & & 5y + 4 & = 0\\
  & & & & 5y & = -4\\
  & & & & y & = -\frac{4}{5}
\end{align*}

$y(5y + 4) > 0$ if $y$ and $5y + 4$ have the same sign, which occurs when $y > 0$ or $y < -4/5$.  Hence, $\Delta \geq 0$ if $y \geq 0$ or $y \leq -4/5$.  However, we showed above that $y = 0$ is not in the range.  Therefore, $y$ is in the range if $y > 0$ or $y < -4/5$.  Hence, the range of the function is
$$\left(-\infty, -\frac{4}{5}\right] \cup (0, \infty)$$

Comment: Well, you should mentioned continuity at some point, no?

Comment: Does that OP know's and how does that sentence contribute to the answer?

Comment: OK..............

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this isn't sufficiently rigorous, but here's my attempt:

Let $p(x) = x^2-x-1$. Being the sum of finitely many nonnegative integer powers of $x$, this is clearly a polynomial and as such is defined for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Via the quadratic formula its roots are $r_{1}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $r_{2}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Furthermore, since the coefficient on $x^2$ is positive we know that the parabola representing this function opens upwards, i.e. $p(x)\lt0$ for $x\in(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$, with $p(x) \ge 0$ otherwise. Via calculus, the minimum of $p(x)$ occurs when $x=\frac{1}{2}$. The value of $p(\frac{1}{2})$ works out to be $\frac{-5}{4}$.

Now consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-x-1}$. You can, in a somewhat dodgy sense (I believe it to be), consider this as being equal to $\frac{p(x)}{(p(x))^2}$, at least as long as $p(x)\neq 0$. Because $(p(x))^2 \gt 0$ for all $p(x)\in (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, if $p(x) \lt 0$ or $p(x) \gt0$, then $f(x) \lt0$ or $f(x)\gt0$. In other words, $f(x)$ and $p(x)$ have the same sign.

That being the case, it is clear that $|f(x)| = \frac{1}{|p(x)|}$. To find the range of $f(x)$ therefore requires you to find the range of $p(x)$, keeping in mind this equality and the fact that they will always have the same sign. For $x\in(-\infty,\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})$, $p(x)\in(0,\infty)$, and likewise for $x\in(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\infty)$, which means that $f(x)\in(0,\infty)$. This accounts for the interval on the RHS of the union in the given answer.

Now consider $x\in(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. Recall that $p(x)\lt0$ over this interval and that $p(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{-5}{4}$. In other words, for all $x$ in this interval, $p(x)\in[\frac{-5}{4},0)$. Since the value of $f(x)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ for all values of $x$ such that $p(x)\neq0$, we can conclude that for values of $x$ in the above interval, $f(x)\in(-\infty,\frac{-4}{5}]$.

Put these intervals together and you get the correct answer, $f(x)\in(-\infty,\frac{-4}{5}]\cup(0,\infty)$.

**Notes:** I did play a bit fast and loose with rigour I think, but I'm pretty confident in my reasoning. You might be wondering, what about the "missing" $x$; that is, what about $x\in[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$? You can work it out if you like (and I encourage you to) and see for yourself that you end up at the same conclusion you get from analysing $p(x)$ and $f(x)$ for $x\in(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. This is because $p(x)$ (and therefore $f(x)$) is symmetric about the line $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

I hope this answer helps. If you or anybody else spots a flaw in my work (or have suggestions as to where I could improve), I'd be appreciative if you could let me know. I'm pretty new at this in earnest, you see. In the meantime: peace!